# Can `internal` access modifier be used to split a class over multiple files?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, code-sharing

The topic I'm currently in is code sharing. It is suggested that using the access modifier `internal` for sharing code between multiple files is possible. But is it? Or do I got it wrong? I can't post the link, because the source is not accessible for everyone.

Is it possible to have the definition of a class in one file (like an interface, or abstract class) and have the implementation of it in another file (and using `internal` here)?

Here is some pseudo code (obviously not working). Definition in one file:

```
internal static class SongLoader
{
    internal async static Task<IEnumerable<Song>> Load();
    internal async static Task<Stream> OpenData();
}
```

Implementation in another file:

```
internal static class SongLoader
{
    internal const string Filename = "songs.json";

    internal static async Task<IEnumerable<Song>> Load()
    {
        // implementation
    }

    internal static Stream OpenData()
    {
        // implemenation
    }
}
```

Or is it possible to have `Load()` defined in one file and `OpenData()` in another, while using `internal` access modifier? Is this possible? How?

Comment: within files in the same assembly : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx

Comment: @Stanley: Yeah, it should be in the same assembly because it gets compiled into the same project (see [Shared Projects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/)).

Comment: `internal` is just a visibility modifier. It has nothing to do with splitting up a class into multiple files. The keyword for that is `partial`. But there is no such thing as a "definition of a class" you are describing. The closest thing are "partial methods", but they must return `void` and they are always private methods.

Comment: @Dennis_E: On the website I mentioned it is stated that *`partial` is sort of variant on class mirroring (use of `internal`)* ... I also believe that for my example only `partial` is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`internal` specifier is used to restrict the class/members being used in other than the containing assembly.

Code sharing is achieved via `partial` classes. You can have part of a class 
in one file and the other part in another file.

In File A

```
public partial class MyClass
{
  public void Foo()
  {
  }
}
```

In File B

```
public partial class MyClass
{
  public void Bar()
  {
  }
}
```

You cannot have declaration in one file and definition in one file as in C++.
If you have such requirements, you should think about `interface` or `abstract` classes.

Comment: In my case hiding a member between different assemblies would be helpful. So I could have different implementations, but also use the same "contract". About the split of declaration and definition: This was only an example how to reach code sharing somehow. In my concrete example `Foo()` is calling `Bar()`, but there are different variants of `Bar()` depending on the assembly.

Comment: You cannot basically have same function implemented specifically for different assemblies. If you tell more about the problem you have, then we can discuss about alternate solutions.

Comment: I want to gain some knowledge in code sharing options. `internal` was mentioned as one of the options (besides `partial`). So `internal` seems not helping with code sharing. Now I tried to use `partial` as you suggested, but I don't see the full benefit here. If you are interested you can look into my tries [here](https://codeshare.io/dDOXz).

Comment: You have marked `OpenData()` as `virtual` in a partial class and you are trying to define `OpenData()` in other part of the partial class. In fact when compiling all members will be within the same class regardless of files. So now there are two methods with ambiguous name & signature. And you are also calling non-static method `OpenData()` from a static method `Load()`.  If you want to have multiple implementation of `OpenData()`, implement them in different classes with same interface and consume that in `Load()` method.

Answer (score 4):

`internal` is an access modifier that deals with what code can access your functions. What you are looking for is the `partial` keyword if you want to break up a class into several files within the same namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

`partial` will not let you define the same function definition twice; you'll need to override or virtualize, or work with a base class if that's what you're aiming for. Partial is handy at times, but it can lead to a somewhat cluttered solution if you're not sure what class can be found where.

Comment: You cannot define the same function twice with partial classes either, which I think is what the OP wants

Comment: You're right, if he's looking for the same function definition twice, that won't work. You'd have to override a base function if that's the route you're looking for. I've added that comment to my answer, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Access modifiers only deal with who can see the code, not how it is implemented.
The closest way to do what you want is by using [abstract classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx).

As an example:

```
internal abstract class SongLoader //under SongLoader.cs
{
    internal async virtual Task<IEnumerable<Song>> Load();
    internal async virtual Task<Stream> OpenData();
}

internal sealed class SongLoaderImplementer : SongLoader //under SongLoaderImplementer.cs
{
    internal override async Task<IEnumerable<Song> Load() {}
    internal override async Task<Stream> OpenData() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know it is too late, but still I'd like to give an answer.
It seems your question comes from "Xamarin university", so:

> Or is it possible to have Load() defined in one file and OpenData() in another, while using internal access modifier? Is this possible? How?

Yes. You should take out `OpenData()` method outside and implement it in each platform-specific project. You don't need to have this method in "Shared project". Like following:

**Android project:**

```
internal class SongLoaderManager
{
    internal static Stream OpenData(string fileName)
    {
        return Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(fileName);
    }
}
```

**IOS project**:

```
internal class SongLoaderManager
{
    internal static Stream OpenData(string fileName)
    {
        return System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName);
    }
}
```

**Shared project:**

```
public static partial class SongLoader
{
    const string Filename = "songs.json";

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<Song>> Load()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(SongLoaderManager.OpenData(Filename))) 
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Song>>(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        }
    }

    // NOT NEEDED ANYMORE
    //public static Stream OpenData()
    //{
    //    // TODO: add code to open file here.
    //    return null;
    //}

}
```

In each plaform you can define their own `OpenData()` method with different behaviours.